# How to refresh Access token of multiple API's being called parallel, When Access token of the all the API's get invalid at the same time?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, access-token, refresh-token

In my React Native application, I get an access token and a refresh token after login.

There is a common function to call the access token again using the refresh token when the access token is invalid

On my home page, there are 6 APIs, but when the access token gets invalid these 6 APIs parallelly call to the common function and refresh the access token. This is making that specific user get blocked.

How to prevent this? blocking the rest of the APIs with a flag when the first API's token becomes invalid is not an option because, before the first response, all the APIs will have refreshed the access token.

The `handleResponse` function gets triggered first then the code reaches `getNewToken` funtions then it reaches the `dispatch(logout());` because the call for accesstoken does not become success and the app crashes because logout is called multiple times.

```
const handleResponse = async (
        res: ApiResponse<BaseResponseProp, BaseResponseProp> | null,
      ) => {
     
          if (res?.data?.error === 'invalid_token') {
            let tokenVal;
            try {
              if (token.refresh_token) {
                tokenVal = await getNewToken(token.refresh_token);
              } else {
                //refresh the public token
                tokenVal = await refreshPublicToken();
              }
              if (tokenVal?.access_token && tokenVal?.access_token.length > 0) {
                const newTokenHeader = {
                  Authorization: `Bearer ${tokenVal.access_token}`,
                };
                invoke({
                  requestHeader: { ...requestHeader, ...newTokenHeader },
                  requestBody,
                  requestParams,
                  requestQuery,
                  url: formattedEndpoint,
                  onResultCallback,
                  onErrorCallback,
                });
                dispatch(setToken(tokenVal));
              } else {
                setInvalidToken(true);
                navigation.dispatch(
                  StackActions.replace(NAVIGATION_SCREENS.ROOT),
                );
                return;
              }
              return;
            } catch (e) {
              const newToken = await refreshPublicToken();
              dispatch(setToken(newToken));
              return;
            }
          }
          const err = new CustomError(
            res?.data?.error || res?.originalError?.message,
            res?.data?.status || 200,
          );
          if (typeof onErrorCallback === 'function') {
            onErrorCallback(err);
          } else if (typeof onError === 'function') {
            onError(err as CustomError);
          }
          handleParseError(err);
        } else {
          const responseData = res?.data as unknown as R;
          if (renderData) {
            setData(res?.data);
          }
          if (typeof onResultCallback === 'function') {
            onResultCallback(res?.data as unknown as R);
          } else if (typeof onResult === 'function') {
            onResult(res?.data);
          }
        }
      };

 const getNewToken = async (refToken: string) => {
    let formattedEndpoint = ENDPOINT.LOGIN;
    let tokenVal = {};
    const header = { refresh_token: refToken };
    const requestQuery = {
      ...REFRESH_AUTH_HEADERS,
      ...header,
    };
    const queryParams = new URLSearchParams({
      ...requestQuery,
    }).toString();
    formattedEndpoint = `${formattedEndpoint}?${queryParams}`;
    const refreshResponse = await api.post<LoginSuccess>(
      formattedEndpoint,
      {},
      {
        headers: basicAuthHeaders,
      },
    );
    if (refreshResponse.status === 200) {
      tokenVal = {
        access_token: refreshResponse.data?.access_token,
        refresh_token: refreshResponse.data?.refresh_token,
        expires_in: refreshResponse.data?.expires_in,
        type: 'private',
      };
    } else {
      // The logout gets called multiple times and app crashes
      dispatch(logout());
      tokenVal = {
        access_token: null,
        token_type: null,
        refresh_token: null,
        expires_in: null,
        scope: null,
        id_token: null,
        type: 'public',
      };
      tokenVal = await refreshPublicToken();
      navigation.dispatch(StackActions.replace(NAVIGATION_SCREENS.ROOT));
    }
    return tokenVal;
  };
```

Comment: blocking the rest of the APIs with a flag when the first API's token becomes invalid is not an option because, before the first response, all the APIs will have refreshed the access token --- can u elaborate this? How can they refresh token when they are blocked.

Comment: @MuhammadUmar Correct me if am wrong since its a asynchronous process all the API will refresh the access token at the same time. If you have any solution please provide me with that

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 synchronization techniques you may need to use when making concurrent API requests in an OAuth architecture:

- Synchronize token refresh
- Synchronize session expiry and user re-authentication

For the first of these, consider [queueing up a collection of promises](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample.final/blob/master/spa/src/plumbing/utilities/concurrentActionHandler.ts) using code like this, and only doing the token refresh for the first of them. Then return the same refresh result for each API request and allow them to resume:

```js
await this._concurrencyHandler.execute(this._performTokenRefresh);
```

To handle session expiry, wait for all API requests to complete, then see if any token refresh requests failed with an `invalid_grant` error code. If at least one of them did, the user session is expired. Therefore re-run the login flow, and do this only once. My code examples do so using [this pattern](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample.final/blob/master/spa/src/views/utilities/viewModelCoordinator.ts#L103).

There are some tricky scenarios for OAuth clients. My [blog post](https://authguidance.com/api-journey-client-side/) summarizes some behaviours. Simulating and rehearsing them is a great way to ensure a resilient app.